# How to save ajax calling values into a variable

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Hope you are all good. I have a problem that is I use an extension i.e. select2 which shows all Products' name in the dropdown list and it works fine to me. In my database, every product has individual price. So, I want to show the sum of all selected products' price in the next of dropdown. So, I used ajax to send the product id to the controller to find the product price. Unfortunately, I can't sum all of product price because when I add new product then previous Id of product gets change then price also gets change. But I want to hold the price of products in a variable when product is selected.

the form code:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'item_list'); ?>
    <?php
    $data = CHtml::listData(Products::model()->findAll(),'id', 'name');
    echo Select2::activeMultiSelect(
        $model, 'item_list', $data, array(
            'required' => 'required',
            'style' => 'width: 270px;',
            'placeholder' => 'Add Product',
            'select2Options' => array(),
            'ajax' => array('type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>$this->createUrl('totalOrderPrice'), //url to call.
                'update'=>'#price', //selector to update
                'data'=>array('item_list'=>'js:this.value'),
            ),
        )
    );

    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'item_list'); ?>
</div>
```

the controller code:

```
...

...

public $prices;
...

...     
public function actionTotalOrderPrice(){
    $data = Products::model()->findByPk(array('id'=>$_POST['item_list']));
    $this->prices += $data->prices;
    echo CHtml::tag('input', array( 'type'=>'text' , 'name'=>'Order[price]' , 'value' => $this->prices));
}
```

I spent a lot of time to solve this problem but anyhow couldn't. Please help someone.

Thanks in advance,
Shimul

Comment: when the product price changes ?

Comment: I would add a data attribute e.g `<option data-price="34" >Product xyz</option>` while creating the dropdown, and use that attribute , no need to fetch sum price each time you add new product :)

Comment: @sakhunzai's answer is likely how I'd implement it as well.  The alternative is instead of using `update` in your ajax, use `success` with a callback function and add logic in the javascript to read the current value, subtract the previous cost (if this was a change to the drop down instead of a new selection), add the new cost, and update the div . . . .

Comment: @ernie ,I am not able to grasp the sentence `I can't sum all of product price because when I add new product then previous Id of product gets change then price also gets change`. Why on earth , the product id changes when a new product is added ?

Comment: @sakhunzai thanks to comment on my post. When I select a new product, ajax sends that product id to the controller's method and the method finds that product's price from the database using the id. Here I'll select multiple product and summing all the product prices and show underneath of dropdown. But I can't.

Comment: So I'm confused if your issue is summing all the prices from the one select box, or if you have multiple select boxes.  If it's multiple selections, then you'll likely need to loop over what you submit via `item_list`, looking up the price for each and summing as you go . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have products schema , I have used another model i.e `User` to give you can example of how it could be done.

```
<div class="row">    
    <?php
    $model=User::model();
    $attribute='products';
    $data =  CHtml::listData(Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select id, concat(RAND()*1000,':',username) as name FROM `User` ")->queryAll(),'id','name');

    echo Select2::activeMultiSelect($model,$attribute, $data,
         array(
            'required' => 'required',
            'style' => 'min-width:200px',           
            'placeholder' => 'Choose User',
            'select2Options'=>array(
                'formatResult'=>'js:format',
                'formatSelection'=>'js:format',
            ),
            'onChange'=>'js:{
                var total=0;
                $($(this).select2("data")).each(function(){
                    total+=this.text.split(":")[0]*1;
                });
                $("#total > label").text(total);
            }',
        )
    );


    $js_format_fun = <<<JS
        function format(opt){
            var price_lbl=opt.text.split(':');              
            return price_lbl[1];
        }
JS;
      Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('select2_format_option', $js_format_fun, CClientScript::POS_READY);
    ?>  
</div>
<br/>
<div id="total"><strong>Total Price: </strong><label></label></div>
```

You will see sth like this:

[image]

The idea is to avoid ajax and add prices to names e.g product name will be of format: `price:name`. You split the price ,name and calculate the total as I give above.

Comment: thanks for you good advice. I'll try. Actually, I am little bit weak in JS. I'll ask once I find any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to look outside YII, you can use javascript for this, out there, you can find JS libraries and frameworks who can help you to save variables and calculate the sum, for example [CanJS](http://canjs.com/) has [can.compute](http://canjs.com/docs/can.compute.html) which has an observable nature so it fires events everytime the sum changes and you can implement function who does the calculation or [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) too has [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) values this two libs are my favorite (I use canjs) they are lightweight and effecient and you can use them just where you need, hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Store it in user session

```
Yii::app()->session['products_prices'] += $data->prices
```

But you will face a problem when you remove items from your list

I don't know this widget but there is certainly a .seralize() function witch will serialize all selected items id into a json string array.

You then can then use this array in a "in" Condition to sum your total.

Comment: thanks @Claude Janz , you are correct and I have already through and became failed. Let my try your following tips.